# Android runtime for Blackberry signing error Previously Signed different app

Tags: android, runtime, blackberry-playbook, sign, blackberry-world

I am porting my Android apps to Blackberry's Android Runtime Environment. I have a pro and demo version of the same app based on a shared library. The version numbers of both the Pro and Demo versions are the same since all changes are made to the library.

If I sign Pro first, signing Demo causes this error

```
Error: Code signing request failed because this file has been previously signed.    eCat_DemoBB.bar /eCat_DemoBB/dist/Android 3.0   D:\Leo\Dropbox\Elect POS\Workspace\eCat_DemoBB\dist\Android 3.0\eCat_DemoBB.bar BlackBerry Previously Signed
```

If I sign Demo first, the error is caused by Pro.
I then need to increment the build in order to sign them both.

It seems like BarSigner keeps track of the build number but neglects the package name??
Is there any way around this?

Comment: If you check sigs between you apps, how is this going to affect it?

Comment: sorry didn't get what you mean by checking signatures? I'm referring to packaging android apps as bar files for app world..